# Blender vs. Unity

Tags: browser, 3d, blender, unity-game-engine

I want to make a 3D game, preferably one that can be played in a browser.  Some people say blender, some say unity.  What are the pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Blender and Unity are not the same things.

[Unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)) is a game engine, which means that its purpose is to create games, and you can program in it using C# or JavaScript. But you cannot make 3d models in it.

While [Blender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_(software)) is a program for modelling mainly. You can create applications or games in it but it is not the program's main purpose.

For Unity, you can create 3D models/animations, and import them but I am not sure if it's compatible with Blender but, it is compatible with Maya.

I would recommend Unity more for making a Game because it also has web support, but it requires installing a plugin.

On the Unity [Website](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Tutorials.html) you can find documentation and examples to help you get started.

Comment: Ah So I was comparing an apple to an orange all along.  Very enlightening answer.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, Blender has a 'game engine' too, but it's not as portable as Unity. With Unity you can make games for browser, Mac, Windows, iPhone and Wii and soon you can do Xbox and Android too. But it has it's price, the free Unity is limited in features and can only be used for webgames and windows/mac computers

Comment: To extend on @Tseng, I'd like to note that I disagree slightly on Unity being more portable. Unity has no linux support, Blender is fully cross platform and 'could' easily work on any system if you ported it yourself. Unity would require official support since it's closed source.

Comment: Disagree that you're comparing apples and oranges, while blenders main purpose is not to be a game engine. it still _has_ a game engine.

Blender has an android port now, which runs the game engine.

Answer (score 10):

At the risk of sounding insolent, I'll have to disagree with [mklfarha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328227/mklfarha)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3886690/11573842). Although it's just my own opinion, I am much more partial to the Blender game engine. When you reach a certain level of proficiency at programming and modelling, the Blender game engine allows much more freedom of choice for game types and in-game mechanics. It's also open-source, meaning you'll never have to worry about copyright.

Having said this, Unity is much better for beginners, as many functions for the game are already built-in, such as the movement of characters and pathfinding. Also, for extreme hardcore programmers needing to squeeze every last drop of power from the computer, Unity would be better, as it is much better optimised graphically and in all other aspects, although if you're encompassed by my last statement, you'd already know all I've said here and more.

Comment: I don't think so, blender is not focused on a game engine, it's more of modelling software, unity is just a game engine and entirely focused on it. So, Blender's not bad as a game engine, not at all, but in my opinion, unity can be better.